# Prevent jquery from reseting background image after fadeOut()

Tags: jquery, html, css, web

I'm doing a number of fadeIn's and fadeOut's with jquery. The final fade (fadeOut()) fades out the entire css table and goes to the css body background image. I have set the background-position to center center. Jquery is resetting the image after the animation is complete to a position of left bottom. I'm looking to prevent this and keep the background image as center center.

I tried putting everything in a figure wrapper instead of in the body, that's the reason for the `<figure>` tag. When I tried this, the screen went completely white after the animation was finished.

HTML & jquery:

```
<html>
<head lang="en">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="site.css" media="screen">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $(".firstFade").fadeIn(5000).delay(10000).fadeOut(7000);
            $(".secondFade").delay(6000).fadeIn(5000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
            $("#tableCell5Text").delay(14500).fadeOut(1000);
            $(".container").delay(15000).fadeOut(7000);
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <figure id="pathImg">
        <div class="container" id="table">
            <div class="container containerRow" id="tableRow">
                <div class="container containerCell" id="tableCell">
                    <img src="images/img1.jpg" alt="" width="150" height="150" class="hidden firstFade" id="img1">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container containerRow" id="tableRow2">
                <div class="container containerCell" id="tableCell2">
                    <img src="images/img2.png" alt="" height="85" width="77" class="hidden firstFade" id="img2">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container containerRow" id="tableRow3">
                <div class="container containerCell" id="tableCell3">
                    <p class="hidden firstFade" id="tableCell3Text">some text</p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container containerRow" id="tableRow4">
                <div class="container containerCell" id="tableCell4">
                    <h2 class="hidden secondFade" id="tableCell4Text">some text</h2>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container containerRow" id="containerRow5">
                <div class="container containerCell" id="containerCell5">
                    <h1 id="tableCell5Text">some text</h1>
                </div>
            </div>
    </div>
    </figure>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#pathImg {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-image: url(images/sunnySkies.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center center;
  background-size: cover;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}

#table {
  display: table;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.containerRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.containerCell {
  display: table-cell;
}

#tableCell {
  height: 20vh;
}

#tableCell2 {
  height:   15vh;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

#tableCell3 {
  height: 10vh;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#tableCell4 {
  height: 5vh;
  vertical-align: top;
}

#tableCell3Text {
  font-family: 'Tangerine', cursive;
  font-size: 300%;
  color: #444444;
}

#tableCell4Text {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #444444;
}

#tableCell5Text {
  font-family: arial;
  color: #444444;
}

#img1 {
  margin: 5vh 0 0 0;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 2px solid #444444;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: gray;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like it's working right. Everything just fades out, is that what you want? https://jsfiddle.net/xaxusamo/

Comment: There is a css background image that it fades out to (css: #pathImg). It fades to that as it is supposed to, center center, but once the animation has completely finished, it resets that background image: #pathImg  to left bottom.

Comment: Oh, and right, I'm sorry. It's because it's in the <figure> HMTL. So when it's in the <figure> HTML, instead of the <body> jquery resets it to the white background of the body.

Comment: Apologies. I edited. it was a typo. pathImg is not supposed to be faded. It is meant to be the final image shown.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually seems like it's working fine for me without the figure. But if you're using the figure then the problem is that you're fading out the .container which sets it to display:none which is taking out all of the height. You need to leave something on the page so that everything doesn't collapse. At the end, the body has no height and that's why you're getting a white screen. So what we'll do is get the height of the largest image and set the body to the height before you fade out.

Change your JQuery to this

```
 $(".firstFade").fadeIn(5000).delay(10000).fadeOut(7000);
 $(".secondFade").delay(6000).fadeIn(5000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000);
 $("#tableCell5Text").delay(14500).fadeOut(1000);
 var $height = $("#table").height();
 $("body").height($height);
 $(".container").delay(15000).fadeOut(7000);
```

Comment: Wow. Genius! I have no idea how you figured that out, but it worked. Thanks! So all I had to do is add a height width to my css for that body?

Comment: yes if you had a height on the body you'd have been fine. Auto height isn't always reliable either so best way is to set the height before you fade out. when you fade out, JQuery sets the element to display:none which is like it doesn't exist and so it has no height. So without content, the body has no height either. There are better ways to structure the code to prevent this, but for you this worked so....

Comment: Awe, bummer. I'm not a programmer. I dabble in it because I find it really cool. Sucks to know my code isn't up to par, but I'm always hesitant to post on here because I already know as much. Thanks for your help, gerek007.

Comment: Your code is fine, it works ;) but there is usually always a better way, even for those that have been programming for years.